# Delete image from db

Tags: javascript, php, database, image

I'm developing a web-page where I can add/delete a photo

I have the code specified under her and It works fine but I'm not sure how to delete the from photo from database when it's removed from the folder- Any ideas?

Here is index.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>How to delete file with jQuery AJAX</title>
        <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src='jquery-3.0.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src='script.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='content'>
                <img src='images/image1.jpg' id='img_1' width='100' height='100'>
                <span data-id='1'>Delete</span>
            </div>
            <div class='content'>
                <img src='images/image2.jpg' id='img_2' width='100' height='100'>
                <span data-id='2'>Delete</span>
            </div>
            <div class='content'>
                <img src='images/image3.jpg' id='img_3' width='100' height='100'>
                <span data-id='3'>Delete</span>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here comes script.js

```html
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Delete
    $('.content span').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
 
        // Selecting image source
        var imgElement_src = $( '#img_'+id ).attr("src");
        
        // AJAX request
        $.ajax({
            url: 'removefile.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {path: imgElement_src},
            success: function(response){
                
                // Changing image source when remove
                if(response == 1){
                    $("#img_" + id).attr("src","images/noimage.png");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And finally  remove file.php

```html
<?php 


if(isset($_POST['path'])){
   $path = $_POST['path']; 

   // Check file exist or not 
   if( file_exists($path) ){ 
      // Remove file 
      unlink($path); 

      // Set status 
      echo 1; 
   }else{ 
      // Set status 
      echo 0; 
   } 
   die;
}
```

I also have an query-file and style.css file (Which I have not shown)

Thanks for your help I advance!

Comment: You should do both of those actions when someone clicks delete (meaning your php script should perform both tasks). If you know how to add them to the database, you shouldn't have any issues removing them either.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not completely sure how to do it with the script.js; Any hints?

Comment: Is `var id = $(this).data('id');` the id of the image?

Comment: Yes, id of the image :-)

Comment: Send that along in AJAX `data` and use the id to perform a `DELETE` query in your php script.

Comment: Please see post below :-)

Comment: You should add new information by editing your question (the `edit` link can be found at the bottom of it), not as an answer. I suggest you delete the answer and add it to the question. Also, show any changes you have made to the ajax call.

Comment: hi again, I just deleted the comment below, thanks! I'm not completely sure how to change the ajax hmm

Comment: Well, as I said earlier, add the id to the data you're sending (here: `data: {path: imgElement_src}`) so that you have it ready for deletion.